# Regex that allows numbers with commas and two decimals

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm trying to make a number input field using the pattern attribute since the regular type number didn't support the validations I needed.

Essentially, I want to allow any numbers that make sense, including `$`, `+` or `-` at the start and a `%` at the end. Also, users should be able to separate their numbers with commas to avoid mistakes on long numbers, but this is not necessary and they should still be able to submit a long number without any type of separation. The field should also allow for decimals.

```
<input required pattern="[+-]?\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?%?" type="text" />
```

I need to allow for the following examples:

Pass:

- 2000
- -20%
- 2,000
- $2,000.00
- 999,999,999,999,999,999,999.99

Fail:

- 123e9
- Anything that has letters on it

This is the regex that I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work, even for the most basic numbers. I've been using scriptular to test my regex, but that doesn't seem to reflect the results of the actual HTML validation.

Regex: `[+-]?\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?%?`

EDIT: For any Ruby on Rails devs, I realized one of my mistakes is that you must escape any backslashes in your regex when you are generating your `text_field`. So for example, the regex in the answer should look like `(?:\\+|\\-|\\$)?\\d{1,}(?:\\,?\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d+)?%?`

Comment: It is a bit unclear what exact requirements you have, but try `pattern="[$]?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?|[+-]?\d+%?)"`. See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/dK1dV0/2). I do not understand whether you want to let percentage have decimals.

Comment: where can be `commas` placed in the number??Can it be like `2,0,00`??

Comment: Sorry, your regex did not work @WiktorStribiżew. I tried `100,000.12` as the first test.
Commas can be placed after every 3 numbers @rock321987. So for example `2,000` or `2000` but not `2,0,00` or `,200`.

Comment: @DavidMeza: See [`^(?:[$]?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?|[+-]?\d+%?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/dK1dV0/4) - it matches `100,000.12` without issues, and check [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gh6sk9eh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `(?:\+|\-|\$)?\d{1,}(?:\,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?%?`

**Explanation:**

- `(?:\+|\-|\$)?` matches either `+` `-` or `$` in-front of a number which is optional as `?` quantifier is used.
- `\d{1,}` matches integer part even if it doesn't have `,`.
- `(?:\,?\d{3})*` matches multiple occurrences of comma separated digits if present.
- `(?:\.\d+)?` matches optional decimal part.
- `%?` matches optional `%` character in the end.
- `?:` stands for non-capturing groups. It will match but won't store it for back-referencing.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ0qW6/4)**

Comment: So, you want to allow `9999999.6789900`, `$-678`, `$+8`, `$4%`? See [this](https://regex101.com/r/fV3pH5/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Lot's of alterations are coming up.

Comment: @noob Thank you. This seems to work as I intended it. Can you please explain why this works and mine didn't? Also, I'm not sure what the `?:` mean inside a parenthesis, so please explain that too. Also I swapped `\$?` and `[+-]?`

Comment: @DavidMeza: This does seems to work at first glance. But as Wiktor said there are few things short.

Comment: @DavidMeza: If you have `$` infront of a number then `%` should appear after it or not ?

Comment: `(?:\+|\-|\$)?` > `[$+-]?`

Comment: @noob I think this is a reasonable approach. I don't want to be overly restrictive.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I don't get it.

Comment: @DavidMeza: I have updated my answer. I think this is what matches all your conditions.

Comment: It works! Thank you for help! If you could just explain how it is different from mine / what it is doing, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: @DavidMeza: Added the explanation.